# Using Wick's Theorem in an example with the harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, operators, harmonic-oscillator, wick-theorem

I understand [Wick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick%27s_theorem) to be,

$$T(x)=\mathcal{N}(x)=\sum:\textbf{all contractions}:$$

And I'm researching combinatorics and quantum theory in general.
How would one connect Wicks theorem to the quantum HO, an example would be appreciated.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/708149/2451

Comment: Unfortunately, the Wikipedia article you linked to is not very good (in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by this notation.  I think most readers will be more comfortable with

$$T\{\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)...\phi(x_m)\}=N\{\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)...\phi(x_m) + \text{all possible contractions}\}.$$

For general operators $\hat{A}, \hat{B}, \hat{C},...,\hat{Z}$, you could write

$$T\{\hat{A}\hat{B}\hat{C}...\hat{Z}\}=N\{\hat{A}\hat{B}\hat{C}...\hat{Z} \text{ }+ \text{all possible contractions of} \text{ } \hat{A}\hat{B}\hat{C}...\hat{Z}\}.$$

The notation $N\{\}$ stands for *normal ordering* and it is the same as ": :" - you may use it if you like it.

I have never heard of Wick's theorem in relation with the quantum harmonic oscillator.  Usually, Wick's theorem is used for evaluating [$S$-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-matrix) elements, in which vacuum expectation values of time-ordered strings of operators appear:

$$\langle 0|T\{\hat{A}\hat{B}\hat{C}...\hat{Z}\}|0 \rangle.$$

Using Wick's theorem, it becomes much easier to calculate such objects.  I will let you find out why!

Answer (score 0):

> I understand Wicks theorem to be,

> $$T(x)=\mathcal{N}(x)=\sum:\textbf{all contractions}:$$

No, the above is incorrect. The time ordering and normal ordering are *not* generally the same, which is why Wick's theorem is useful.

> And I'm researching combinatorics and quantum theory in general.
> How would one connect Wicks theorem to the quantum HO, an example would be appreciated.

In studying the quantum harmonic oscillator, we introduce lowering (annihilation) and raising (creation) operators:
$$
\hat a
$$
and
$$
\hat a^\dagger\;,
$$
respectively. We have, as usual, $\hat a|0> = 0$ and $[a,a^\dagger] = 1$ and $\hat H = \hat a \hat a^\dagger (\hbar \omega_0 + 1/2)$.

These $a$ operators have time dependence in the Heisenberg picture (in the same way as all operators):
$$
\hat a(t) = e^{iHt}\hat a e^{-iHt}\;,
$$
*etc*.

The time ordering, for example, of $a(t)$ and $a^\dagger(t')$ is:
$$
T(a(t)a^\dagger(t')) = \theta(t-t')a(t)a^\dagger(t') + \theta(t'-t)a^\dagger(t')a(t)\;.
$$

The normal ordering, for example, of $a(t)$ and $a^\dagger(t')$ is:
$$
N(a(t)a^\dagger(t')) = a^\dagger(t')a(t)\;.
$$

Wick's theorem can be used to relate these.

For example:
$$
<0|T(a(t)a^\dagger(t'))|0> = \theta(t-t')e^{-i\hbar \omega_0 (t-t')} + <0|N(a(t)a^\dagger(t'))|0>
$$